# Assertion fail with GetDC() (using mfc)

Tags: c++, mfc

So, I keep getting an assertion fail:

```
_AFXWIN_INLINE CDC* CWnd::GetDC()
    { ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd)); return CDC::FromHandle(::GetDC(m_hWnd)); }
```

And I checked the call stack and the method called before the method above is:

```
CDC *pDC = GetDC();
```

I'm not sure what is wrong with any of this, but I would like some help. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a little more context?  Looks like `m_hWnd` is bad but without seeing how it was created and such it's just a guess.

Comment: its been a while but if I remember correctly, if you are getting the DC in OnPaint you need to create a CPaintDC. But more context is needed on when you are calling GetDC

Comment: @Servé `CPaintDC` is a convenience, not a necessity. No application is ever required to instantiate a `CPaintDC`.

Answer (score 1):

If you get this Assertion you use the CWNd::GetDC function without having a created window. Or the window is already destroyed.